# PHP array and Worpdress reformating

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I have an array in PHP in this format (var_dump):

```
array(4) {
[0] => int(367)
[1] => int(356)
[2] => int(345)
[3] => int(389)
}
```

These values were generated by my own function and integer numbers are post IDs. Now I need to use this array in WP_Query for post__not_in.

Is there any way how to reformat my array to proper format like this?

```
array('367','356','345','389')
```

Comment: So you need the integers converted to strings?

Comment: Those should not need to be strings, integers work fine. Sounds like there isn't any _actual_ problem to solve here. If you can do `var_dump($foo)` in one place, you can probably do `'post__not_in' => $foo` in another ...

Comment: @CBroe Yes I can do that, but excluding of posts in array does not work. I thought the reason is the formating and integer, but I am not sure right now.

Comment: @j08691 I am not sure. Do you think echo of strings will help?

Comment: _"I thought the reason is the formating and integer, but I am not sure right now."_ - you should be able to quickly verify that, by hard-coding an array with the values as strings in that place.